# wget TLSv1 behaves the same as TLSv1_2

Tags: security, wget, curl, ssl

I used wireshark to compare `curl --tlsv1.0` vs `--tlsv1.2`

The server handshake obediently uses TLSv1.0 for servers that support it (the point is to check to validate they don't):

```
wget url --no-check-certificate --secure-protocol=TLSv1 behaves the same as --secure-protocol=TLSv1_2: the handshake uses TLS1_2 every time.
```

Obviously there is no `--secure-protocol=TLS1_0`. How do I force wget to obey using 1_0 not 1_2?

```
wget: --secure-protocol: Invalid value ‘TLSv1_0’
```

GNU Wget 1.17.1 built on cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the source code, you can see the possibilities.  [This slice](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git/tree/src/gnutls.c#n564) looks like what you want:

```
case secure_protocol_tlsv1:
  err = gnutls_priority_set_direct (session, "NORMAL:-VERS-SSL3.0", NULL);
  break;

case secure_protocol_tlsv1_1:
  err = gnutls_priority_set_direct (session, "NORMAL:-VERS-SSL3.0:-VERS-TLS1.0", NULL);
  break;
```

which (see [init.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git/tree/src/init.c#n1614)) appears to be `"tlsv1_1"`:

```
static bool
cmd_spec_secure_protocol (const char *com, const char *val, void *place)
{
  static const struct decode_item choices[] = {
    { "auto", secure_protocol_auto },
    { "sslv2", secure_protocol_sslv2 },
    { "sslv3", secure_protocol_sslv3 },
    { "tlsv1", secure_protocol_tlsv1 },
    { "tlsv1_1", secure_protocol_tlsv1_1 },
    { "tlsv1_2", secure_protocol_tlsv1_2 },
    { "pfs", secure_protocol_pfs },
  };
  int ok = decode_string (val, choices, countof (choices), place);
  if (!ok)
    fprintf (stderr, _("%s: %s: Invalid value %s.\n"), exec_name, com, quote (val));
  return ok;
}
```